# Recursion schemes with several types

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, recursion-schemes

Right now, I've got an AST for expression that's polymorphic over the type of recursion:

```
data Expr a = Const Int
            | Add a a
```

This has been incredibly useful by allowing me to use a type for plain recursion (`Fix Expr`) and another one when I need to attach extra information (`Cofree Expr ann`).

The issue occurs when I want to introduce another type into this recursion scheme:

```
data Stmt a = Compound [a]
            | Print (Expr ?)
```

I'm not sure what to put for the `Expr` term without introducing additional type variables and breaking compatibility with all the general functions I've already written.

Can this be done, and if so, is it a useful pattern?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The recursion-schemes perspective is to view recursive types as fixed points of functors. The type of expressions is the fixed point of the following functor:

```
data ExprF expr = Const Int
                | Add expr expr
```

The point of changing the name of the variable is to make explicit the fact that it is a placeholder for the actual type of expressions, that would otherwise be defined as:

```
data Expr = Const Int | Add Expr Expr
```

In `Stmt`, there are two recursive types, `Expr` and `Stmt` itself. So we put two holes/unknowns.

```
data StmtF expr stmt = Compound [stmt]
                     | Print expr
```

When we take a fixpoint with `Fix` or `Cofree`, we are now solving a system of two equations (one for `Expr`, one for `Stmt`), and that comes with some amount of boilerplate.

Instead of applying `Fix` or `Cofree` directly, we generalize, taking those fixpoint combinators (`Fix`, `Cofree`, `Free`) as parameters in the construction of expressions and statements:

```
type Expr_ f = f ExprF
type Stmt_ f = f (StmtF (Expr_ f))
```

Now we can say `Expr_ Fix` or `Stmt_ Fix` for the unannotated trees, and `Expr_ (Flip Cofree ann)`, `Stmt_ (Flip Cofree ann)`. Unfortunately we have to pay another LOC fee to make the kinds match, and the types get ever more convoluted.

```
newtype Flip cofree a f b = Flip (cofree f a b)
```

(This also assumes we want to use the same `Fix` or `Cofree` everywhere at the same times.)

---

Another representation to consider is ([called HKD nowadays](http://reasonablypolymorphic.com/blog/higher-kinded-data/)):

```
data Expr f = Const Int
            | Add (f Expr) (f Expr)

data Stmt f = Compount [f Stmt]
            | Print (f (Expr f))
```

where you only abstract from annotation/no-annotation (`f = Identity` or `(,) ann`) and not from recursion.

Comment: The generalization step with the type synonyms was the crucial step I couldn't come up with, but it all seems so clear now that it's in front of me. Thanks!

Comment: How would you do this with Expr also referring to Stmt like if Expr had a `Block [Stmt] Expr`

Comment: In the case of mutually recursive types you'll need a fixpoint operation for functors with multiple parameters: `ExprF expr stmt`, `StmtF expr stmt`. The recursion-schemes library won't cut it anymore. I think compdata is a good alternative, but it's a bit more sophisticated. It seems easiest to roll your own recursion schemes at that point.