# How to use recursion-schemes to `cata` two mutually-recursive types?

Tags: haskell, recursion-schemes

I started with this type for leaf-valued trees with labeled nodes:

```
type Label = String
data Tree a = Leaf Label a 
            | Branch Label [Tree a]
```

I have some folds I'd like to write over this tree, and they all take the form of catamorphisms, so let's let `recursion-schemes` do the recursive traversal for me:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor, DeriveFoldable, DeriveTraversable, TemplateHaskell, TypeFamilies #-}
import Data.Functor.Foldable.TH (makeBaseFunctor)
import Data.Functor.Foldable (cata)

type Label = String
data Tree a = Leaf Label a 
            | Branch Label [Tree a]
makeBaseFunctor ''Tree

allLabels :: Tree a -> [Label]
allLabels = cata go
  where go (LeafF l _) = [l]
        go (BranchF l lss) = l : concat lss
```

And all is well: we can traverse a tree:

```
λ> allLabels (Branch "root" [(Leaf "a" 1), Branch "b" [Leaf "inner" 2]])
["root","a","b","inner"]
```

But that definition of Tree is a little clunky: each data constructor needs to handle the Label separately. For a small structure like Tree this isn't too bad, but with more constructors it would be quite a nuisance. So let's make the labeling its own layer:

```
data Node' a = Leaf' a
             | Branch' [Tree' a]
data Labeled a = Labeled Label a
newtype Tree' a = Tree' (Labeled (Node' a))
makeBaseFunctor ''Tree'
makeBaseFunctor ''Node'
```

Great, now our Node type represents the structure of a tree without labels, and Tree' and Labeled conspire to decorate it with labels. But I no longer know how to use `cata` with these types, even though they are isomorphic to the original `Tree` type. `makeBaseFunctor` doesn't see any recursion, so it just defines base functors that are identical to the original types:

```
$ stack build --ghc-options -ddump-splices
...
newtype Tree'F a r = Tree'F (Labeled (Node' a))
...
data Node'F a r = Leaf'F a | Branch'F [Tree' a]
```

Which like, fair enough, I don't know what I'd want it to generate either: `cata` expects a single type to pattern-match on, and of course it can't synthesize one that's a combination of two of my types.

So what's the plan here? Is there some adaptation of `cata` that works here if I define my own Functor instances? Or a better way to define this type that avoids duplicate handling of Label but still is self-recursive instead of mutually recursive?

I think this question is probably related to [Recursion schemes with several types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51073110/recursion-schemes-with-several-types), but I don't understand the answer there: `Cofree` is so far mysterious to me, and I can't tell whether it's essential to the problem or just a part of the representation used; and the types in that question are not quite mutally-recursive, so I don't know how to apply the solution there to my types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[One answer to the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51073592/625403) mentions adding an extra type parameter, so that instead of `Tree (Labeled a)` we use `Tree Labeled a`:

```
type Label = String
data Labeled a = Labeled Label a deriving Functor
data Tree f a = Leaf (f a)
              | Branch (f [Tree f a])
```

This way, a single type (`Tree`) is responsible for the recursion, and so `makeBaseFunctor` should recognize the recursion and abstract it over a functor. And it does do that, but the instances it generates aren't quite right. Looking at `-ddump-splices` again, I see that `makeBaseFunctor ''Tree` produces:

```
data TreeF f a r = LeafF (f a) | BranchF (f [r]) deriving (Functor, Foldable, Traversable)
type instance Base (Tree f a) = TreeF f a
instance Recursive (Tree f a) where
  project (Leaf x) = LeafF x
  project (Branch x) = BranchF x
instance Corecursive (Tree f a) where
  embed (LeafF x) = Leaf x
  embed (BranchF x) = Branch x
```

but this doesn't compile, because the Recursive and Corecursive instances are only correct when `f` is a functor. In the worst case, I can copy the splices into my file directly and add the constraint myself:

```
data TreeF f a r = LeafF (f a) | BranchF (f [r]) deriving (Functor, Foldable, Traversable)
type instance Base (Tree f a) = TreeF f a
instance Functor f => Recursive (Tree f a) where
  project (Leaf x) = LeafF x
  project (Branch x) = BranchF x
instance Functor f => Corecursive (Tree f a) where
  embed (LeafF x) = Leaf x
  embed (BranchF x) = Branch x
```

After which I can use `cata` in a way very similar to the original version in my question:

```
allLabels :: Tree Labeled a -> [Label]
allLabels = cata go
  where go (LeafF (Labeled l _)) = [l]
        go (BranchF (Labeled l lss)) = l : concat lss
```

However, dfeuer explains in a (now-deleted) comment that `recursion-schemes` has a facility already for saying "please generate the base functor as you normally would, but include this constraint in the generated class instances". So, you can write

```
makeBaseFunctor [d| instance Functor f => Recursive (Tree f a) |]
```

to generate the same instances that I produced above by hand-editing the splices.